# Debugging a strange 404 response

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to help someone debug a strange 404 behaviour. If you go to the site: https://www.dpme.gov.za and click on the `Key Focus Areas` menu, and then the `Evaluations` link, you get to [this URL](https://www.dpme.gov.za/keyfocusareas/evaluationsSite/Pages/default.aspx). From there, if you click the `Evaluations Repository` link in the left hand menu, you should get a 404 error.

The link that give the 404 error is https://evaluations.dpme.gov.za/, which is a redirect from the insecure version http://evaluations.dpme.gov.za/ that you would have clicked. The strange behaviour is that, if you go directly to that link, it typically doesn't return a 404, and if you wait for a few minutes and refresh the page, then the 404 goes away - but often I then find if I navigate back to the `www` subdomain, then that site starts returning (temporary) 404 errors.

Furthermore, if I am getting a 404 and I put the request into Postman, it returns with a `200` response, even though I continue to get the `404` error in the browser. I've checked the Request headers and I can't find anything that would differentiate the two requests.

I unfortunately don't have access to the server, but have been asked to try help/guide the IT dept to resolve this issue, as people are not getting to the Evaluations repository when they navigate via the main site. The two sites are separate sites that I believe run on the same IIS server. Any help / ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get more error messages? For example, in the console, if you cannot access the server, it is difficult to find the problem. If you can, you only need to use failed request tracking to get detailed error messages and then solve the problem.